# UseState shows previous value after updating

Tags: reactjs, state

actully,while updating a variable in react we are using set state.but using the setstate value is not updated still showing previous value.if i understand anything wrong in react.pls help me to understand.
anyone help me..how to update state in reactJS..

```
//HTML CODE for select
<select onChange={changeSelect}>
        <option value="1">City 1</option>
        <option value="2">City 2</option>
        <option value="3">City 3</option>
      </select>


//below method will trigger while selecting value in html

const changeSelect=(e)=>{
    console.log("value from dropdown",e.target.value);
     setSelectedCity(e.target.value);
     //ony previous value is coming..
     console.log("value in the variable "+selectedCity)

  }
```

below image is console screenshot of browser

[image]

Comment: You have hook examples in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous. Do what you want with the updated value in a side effect.

Move your console.log in a useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(selectedCity)
}, [selectedCity])
```